# Question about appealing an account Google disabled, associated with a youtube account

Tags: youtube, google

I created a Google account, the intention and usage, was to test uploading youtube videos with a program. The videos had no adult or sexual content in them. Some videos had some clips of videos from the BWF(Badminton World) channel who like blocking anybody that takes even a 30 second clip from one of their videos. So I had some messages saying that I couldn't make certain videos public and couldn't even make some of the videos unlisted, so some of the videos were forced, to be private only.

There were less than 10 videos on the channel, the videos were less than 5 minutes in length.

None of the videos were important.

I merely created the youtube channel to test automatic uploading. And I am testing automatic uploading because Youtube is broken, and when uploading multiple clips through selecting a bunch of them and using drag and drop, the order gets messed up.  And it's a bit tedious to upload one by one. So I wanted to look at using some software to upload clips one by one, in the correct order.  The software is just some python that clicks some buttons automatically.

I also used a Proxy/VPN web browser extension like SurfShark while doing it.. and many people nowadays use that kind of VPN proxy.

I could appeal but I wonder if I did break their rules, if they had some anti-bot usage rule.  Though I used hardly any bandwidth. The videos are tiny. It was a test account. And lucky it was just a test account because it shows how untrustworthy and unreliable Google is..

I got this message when trying to log in

[image]

And there was a link to this page too

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/40695?visit_id=638009015193831139-1302755706&p=disabled_multiple_signin2&rd=1

By the way this guy https://techxataka.com/this-youtube-channel-has-more-than-two-million-videos-and-uploads-more-than-one-per-minute-as-easy-as-stealing-on-stack-overflow/  is a huge spammer . My videos weren't even public and were no more than 10. That guy has millions.

I have another youtube account that is fine that i've got a few hundred videos on that aren't public. And it's fine. And i've been wanting to use a python script to upload videos to it but now of course i'm very wary of doing so. Since my test has triggered google's bot.

I have noticed issues with Google for example once when I wanted to write a (positive) review for a company i'd visited.. For anonymity I didn't want to use my main account so I created a new account to do it.  They didn't publish the review even after I appealed and tweeted them about it, and they did nothing.  As long as they don't block my main account it's not so terrible.. though i'll try backing it up.

I'm wondering though, if given the description i've given, how Google is re reactivating google accounts.. And if using a python script to click buttons to upload videos , or using a VPN Proxy,  one or the other or a combination, is commonly a trigger for getting blocked from accessing the account you do that with?